# Navbar on ArcGIS JS API causing locator to behave buggy

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, html, css

I have added a nav bar with combo boxes to extend an ArcGIS JS API application further.  When a location is selected on the map the point does not appear and I receive this error.

**Failed to get text for stylesheet 59: No style sheet with given id found**

Additionally, when the map is zoomed in, the point will appear, albeit at another intersection or place close to where the user initially clicks.

[image]

```
    div id="divMainContainer" dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="headline"
    gutters="false" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative">
    <div id="map" class="map" region="center" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane"

     < class='navbar' style="height:450px;">


<div class='navbar-inner'>
    <div class='container'>
        <a class='brand'></a>
        <ul class='nav'>
            <li><a></a></li>
            <li><a></a></li>

       </ul>
        <form class="navbar-search pull-left">

            <col>
               <td align="left" style="width: 70%"> 
                                            <select style="width: 80px"> <select id="Select1" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"
                                                style="width: 250px; background-color:Black; font:black;  color: white;" onchange="ValidateRequestType">
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
```

edit: http://jsbin.com/bogosuqari/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: can you post a simplified jsbin or fiddle?

Comment: I have added a jsbin link.